# How do I group tasks in MS-Project?

Tags: ms-project, tasks

[image]

This is my first ms-project. I want to plan the production and external operations of our plant.
*Production of reference #1* is something that will likely happen every 4 to 6 weeks (every time I receive a purchasing order).
Is there any way I can group and save all these tasks together?

What I want is, instead of creating all tasks everytime I receive a PO, to select something like "Production of reference #1" and have all the tasks automatically created, and I will only need to decide when first task starts.

Is that possible?

Comment: @Tob , you've answered the question. Why not make it an answer ?

Comment: @GürkanÇetin done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group tasks by clicking on *summary task* under a headline task as @самиJ.D. pointed out. The corresponding option should be at the *task* menu. It might be possible to copy & paste the headline task (incl. the subtasks) and set a start date / relationship for the headline task.

Comment: The trick is to link only the main task, for copy-paste to work effectively.  The subtasks can be inter-linked.

Comment: So, what I have to do is to select a group of tasks and click on "summary task" so one global task is created, which includes all the other subtasks. In order to copy-paste that, I need to copy-paste the main global task. 
What I don't understand now, after checking it, is what's the differene between summary and indenting the tasks.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @самиJ.D. Sorry, translated it from my language, seems like MS picked a better word in yours.